# JQuery check if clicked li has child ol/ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a solution on how to detect if a li has a child ul or ol i discovered jquerys [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) which is pretty awesome apart from I need to detect if only the actual clicked li has a child ol, not any of its siblings. Are there any ways of doing this? The documentation doesnt cover this.

**HTML**

```
    <ol>
    <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 3 has ol</a>
             <ol>
                <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 5</a></li>
                <li><a class="delete-li" href="">Page 6</a></li>
             </ol> 
        </li>
 </ol>
```

**JS**

```
$('.delete-li').live('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
item_id = $(this).attr('rel');  
clicked = $(this);
////////////////////
    //check if has sub pages
            if(clicked.has('ol')){
              answer = confirm('This will delete all sub pages and content are you sure?');
              console.log(answer);
              if(answer===true){gogogo=true;   
                  }else{gogogo=false;}
                       }else{ gogogo=true;}
        //if yes run AJAX delete
        if(gogogo===true){
        alert('LI REMOVED');
}
////////////////

    });
```

Checkout the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqzVN/) for the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`has` returns a jQuery object which is always `true`, as your handler is bound to `a` elements you can use `next` method and `length` property:

```
if ( clicked.next('ol').length )
```

Note that `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-li',  function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var gogogo = false, $clicked = $(this), item_id = this.rel;  
    ////////////////////
    //check if has sub pages
    if ($clicked.next('ol').length) {
        gogogo = confirm('This will delete all sub pages and content are you sure?');
        // console.log(gogogo);
    }

    if (gogogo === true) {
        alert('LI REMOVED');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMF42/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/ZqzVN/1/ also could you provide any insight into why .length is there?

Comment: @TommyArnold I have updated the answer, `length` returns the number of selected elements in jQuery collection, if the length of the selected elements is more than 0 then the `if` statement valuates to true.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the click handler to the `a` element. You need to be in reference to the `li`.

```
listItem = $(this).parent('li');
//check if has sub pages
if (listItem.find('ol').length) {
   ...
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwGwX/)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function on `<a>` tag, which doesnt have child. If you want to get deeper you need to refer from his parent `<li>`.

```
$('.delete-li').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent('li').children('ol').length) {
        answer = confirm('This will delete all sub pages and content are you sure?');
        alert(answer);
    } else {
        alert('dont');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGmz6/